# Javascript function not working in adobe acrobat

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

Below javascript code is not working in adobe acrobat pro:

```
function CheckDate(){
    var Date = this.getField("enrollDate").value;
    var currentdate = new Date().getDate();
    if(Date < currentdate){
        app.alert("Date should be greater than");
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What part is not working? it's always returning false? it doesn't run? It might be something to do with `this.getField("enrollDate").value` - Can you confirm that this is a proper date value?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I wouldn't call your variable `Date`, as that's the name of the date object in JavaScript.  I would just change it to:

```
// lowercase 'date' doesn't conflict with 'Date' object
var date = this.getField( 'enrollDate' ).value;
```

Comment: Are there any console errors?  Are you sure that `this.getField("enrollDate")` is returning an object?  And that value is of type `Date`?  Also, you shouldn't compare `Date` objects with inequality operators.  It may work thanks to JavaScripts coercion mechanism, but it's cleaner and more obvious to do `date.getTime() < currentdate.getTime()`.